# Simple loop through columns by name in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to loop through columns in my df, but it gives `null` values:

```
for (i in names(train_num)){
    print(train_num$i)
}
```

I think it's because `i` is a `string`, so `train$"column_name"` is not going to work. How can I change that? Or maybe any alternative?

PS: I need to loop through them by name and call the variable in the loop by its name, as I will do transformation with each variable given a set of conditions.

Comment: change train_num$i to train_num[,i]

Comment: `print(train_num[[i]])` is another option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Wen's comment noted, you can use the square bracket to subset, which accepts column names as string. However, if you are trying to loop over the columns, it makes more sense to just loop over the columns. Data frames are lists of columns, so there's no need to use `names()` and subsets at all.

Lastly, whatever transformation you're trying to do is likely better served by a different method, such as an `_apply` or `purrr::map_` function, or by `dplyr::mutate_all`.

```r
df <- head(airquality)
for (i in names(df)){
  print(df[, i])
}
#> [1] 41 36 12 18 NA 28
#> [1] 190 118 149 313  NA  NA
#> [1]  7.4  8.0 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9
#> [1] 67 72 74 62 56 66
#> [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

for (col in df){
  print(col)
}
#> [1] 41 36 12 18 NA 28
#> [1] 190 118 149 313  NA  NA
#> [1]  7.4  8.0 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9
#> [1] 67 72 74 62 56 66
#> [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Created on 2018-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score -1):

Use `colnames(df)`. For example,

```
colnames(mtcars)
```

Gives you a vector of column names in order:

```
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"
[7] "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for (col.name in colnames(mtcars)) {
    print(col.name)
}
```

And that gives you:

```
[1] "mpg"
[1] "cyl"
[1] "disp"
[1] "hp"
[1] "drat"
[1] "wt"
[1] "qsec"
[1] "vs"
[1] "am"
[1] "gear"
[1] "carb"
```